# Making WebView as fast as possible just to get html source

Tags: java, android, webview

In my Activity I am setting up the WebView in order to extract source from the page. What I did is basically extend a webviewclient so that I could run a script and get the page content.

Snippet from by Activity:

```
this.webView.setWebViewClient(new MyExtractingWebViewClient(getApplicationContext(), new ValueCallback() {
                public final void onReceiveValue(Object obj) {
                    doStuff();
                }
            }));

this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            this.webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            this.webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.webView.loadUrl(str);
```

What I do in MyExtractingWebViewClient is basically run a script to get the html.
Since my goal is to only get the html as a String and then perform some actions on it, I was wondering if was possible to get the whole thing much faster.
For instance, I have no use to show the webview to the user so I guess could simply call             `this.webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` but I am sure this would not make a big difference.
Surely disabling javascript would make things much faster but sadly I need it enabled.

Comment: If all you want is the html as a string, don't use a WebView. WebViews are browsers, they're going to render the html. Just download it instead.  If you need something else you need to make your question clearer about it.

Comment: What you're saying is correct. The thing is I need to login first in order to get the content I want.

Comment: I'd look at finding another way to get that data, such as an API.  If you're trying to scrape a website, especially one with a login, your code is going to be fragile, break frequently when they have even minor UI updates, and likely be against their terms of service leaving you open to lawsuit.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan. It does not matter if one uses a webview or another component downloading the same page. The source text will be the same. All OP wants is to grab the source before the webview starts rendering. So the problem is only how to grab the source. Good luck!

Comment: @blackapps By the same token it doesn't matter if I pick up a piece of paper with my hands, or spend 10 years building a Rube Goldberg device to do so.  But one is the right tool for the job, the other is overly complicated and more prone to random failure.  Unless you need to display HTML, you shouldn't use a webview to download a file.

Comment: @GabeSechan but of course if it would be possible to avoid rendering process then it would be irrelevant if I use a an android webview or a third-party API to get the source.

Comment: If you really want to stick with a awe view I would disable loading all images and other unnecessary files. WebViewClient as methods like shouldOverrideUrlLoading with allows you to block requests.